# Derby DB server start by java code

Tags: java, derby

I do not want to install a database server on target machine. It is possible that we can simply ship a jar file with the database embedded in it, and not worry about installing a database server separately?
    I created one application in netbeans using derby and it is working fine in my pc but when i am running on other machine it is giving me an Exception
    My code is

```
 System.setProperty("derby.drda.startNetworkServer", "true");
 try {
     NetworkServerControl serverControl = new NetworkServerControl();
     serverControl.start(new PrintWriter(System.out, true));
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

For connection i wrote this code

```
 public static Connection  getderbyConnection() throws     ClassNotFoundException, SQLException    
  {  
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/XLS_Uniquewordlist;create=true";  
      String user = "root";  
      String password = "mantra";  
      Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");  
      return (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);     

  }
```

I am getting this exception

> ```
> Exception in thread "DRDAConnThread_2" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> ```
>
> org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.EnginePreparedStatement.getVersionCounter()J
>         at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAStatement.explicitPrepare(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parsePRPSQLSTT(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
>       May 12, 2015 5:17:59 PM xls_parser.Main_panel btnokActionPerformed
>       SEVERE: null
>       java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE: -20001, SQLSTATE: 42X05, SQLERRMC: APP.UNIQUEWORDLIST42X05
>         at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)

Comment: looks like the other machine has different version of jersey.

Comment: Looks like you have a version conflict.

Comment: Just a remark: If you have still problems with derby, you can try sqlite db as well. That driver creates only a local DB file, so it depends less on the target environment. + you don't have to start the derby server separately. (But only if you have the possibility and time to change db)